# Using keyword "and" in containstable function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run `containstable` on "test1 and test2" and would like to run the test on the keyword "and" as well.

However the following gives me an error:

```
containstable(table_name, column_name, 'test1 AND "and" test2')
```

The syntax from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) does not indicate whether such keywords are allowed or not and if they are how they can be used.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, the answer is:

```
containstable(table_name, column_name, 'test1 AND "and test2"')
```

Note that the double quotes go around `"and test2"` and not just `"and"`

Answer (score 1):

Look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

and one of the examples works similarly to your test.

```
containstable(table, column, '("sweet and savory" NEAR sauces) OR
    ("sweet and savory" NEAR candies)')
```

Modify the constraints to match your data.

Edit: I should also specify that `'test1 AND "and" test2'` is not a boolean condition at any rate. Try:

```
'(test1 AND "and") OR (test2 AND "and")'
```

or something similar that will evaluate to a boolean condition.